# How to stop (not unregister) a running service worker like in chrome dev tools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, service-worker

In google dev tools -> `Application` -> `Service Workers` there is an option to unregister a service worker. If you do this the status of this service worker will also change to `stopped`.

When I unregister the service worker programmatically from the console with something like `await (await navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations())[0].unregister()` I get a `true` from the promise, so the service worker was unregistered. But the status in dev tools does not change into `stopped`. How can I programmatically stop the service worker like the dev tools are doing it when clicking `Unregister` or `stop`.

The service worker I am working with is created with create-reac-app / workbox. Find a basic example here: https://pwa-cra.vercel.app/

Comment: If you want to stop the worker from devtools console, the only solution is to open another devtools for devtools itself and send [ServiceWorker.stopWorker](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/ServiceWorker/#method-stopWorker) command that devtools itself is sending when you click the `Stop` label in Application panel. I think it's much more convenient to click the label manually...

Comment: Doing this manually from console is just an example how to do it programmatically. Eventually this should be done by the application itself.

Comment: There's no such method generally per the specification.